# User-contol для проверки алгоритмов c#

Tags: c#, button, usercontrol

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать. Создаю user-control. На нем кнопка. По нажатию должны выполняться сначала стандартные действия (выгружаем из папки файлы с информацией), потом перегруженные пользователем (На каждом файле запускаем алгоритм). Поскольку файлы большие, то пользовательский алгоритм надо бы запустить внутри стандартной обработки. По сути user-contol используется для тестирования различных алгоритмов. Какой механизм нужно использовать для  checkUserAlgoritm() ???  Делегат, интерфейс?

Что-то вроде того

```
<!-- language: c# -->
    private void doAnalysisButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     foreach (string file in files)            
     {
           if (OpenFile(file)) //если удалось успешно открыть файл
           {
                checkUserAlgoritm();
           }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Очень невнятно сформулирован вопрос. что именно вы хотите получить? И при чем тут UserControl?

Comment: Что такое "пользовательский алгоритм"? Код, который пишет пользователь, и который вы хотите запустить?

Comment: Хочу получить user-control, который можно кинуть на форму. По нажатию на кнопку на этом контроле  должны вычитываться данные из файлов. Затем на этих данных (условно, массивах) должны выполняться РАЗНЫЕ алгоритмы, которые лежат в разных проектах (какой именно алгоритм будет выполняться должен решать пользователь, добавляющий контрол к себе на форму.)

Comment: Не-не-не. `UserControl` нужен лишь для отображения. Он должен вызывать код бизнес-логики (лучше всего, понятно, через `ICommand`), и вся работа должна происходить там. Разделяйте логику и представление!

Answer (score 1):

Я голосую за делегат. Точнее - за Event. Это классическое решение в таких случаях, когда необходимо создать "точки расширения".